# How to get rid of link underline in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of the blue link underline in Chrome?

Comment: By using CSS?  What does this have to do with Python or Django?

Comment: You'd do it with CSS but it's not specific to only Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Via CSS with `text-decoration: none;`

EDIT:

For the actual full CSS

```
a, a:hover, a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be more specific than that. If you're talking about just removing link underline, then you can do it simply by css using so:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This has nothing to do with chrome though, it's generic.